# Apache2 with Flask and Pysnmp - OSError: Cannot load native module 'Cryptodome.Cipher._raw_ecb': Trying '_raw_ecb.pyd':

Tags: apache, flask, mod-wsgi, pysnmp, pycryptodome

I use the combination of Apache2, mod_wsgi, flask, pysnmp - SNMPv3 on Windows 10 environment. I integrated flask with apache2 using mod_wsgi. Flask application does SNMP related stuffs, for which i use pysnmp module. I use SNMP v3 which does encryption and decryption. After integration, on running apache2 i get following error.

```
OSError: Cannot load native module 'Cryptodome.Cipher._raw_ecb': Trying '_raw_ecb.pyd'
cannot load library C:\\Users\\...\\Lib\\site-packages\\Cryptodome\\Util\\..\\Cipher\\_raw_ecb.pyd: error 0x45a.
```

Any suggestions or help will be greatly appreciated.

**Note:-** When i use flask development server, i didn't get this error. Everything works fine.

Comment: This may have something to do with Windows. Try [googling for error 0x45a](https://www.google.com/search?q=error+0x45a). It seems to happen to many applications, not only to Python.

Comment: @IlyaEtingof I didn't get anything related on searching that error. If its something related to windows, it shouldn't be working on flask development server too.

Comment: Could it depend on the user under which you run the tool? Or file system view? Just sharing my thoughts...